# How to convert an mp3 to an flv with a background: conversion errors

Tags: mp3, flash-cs5, flv

I'm trying to convert an mp3 to an flv for use in a custom player we already had built.

I can import the mp3 to the timeline, but it's 30 minutes of talking, and you can only add so many frames at a time. That's tedious! We have a lot of these to do.

I then tried the simple import URL option and got it to stream. I put a stop() on the first frame and boom, that works when I test in Flash CS5.

But to convert to flv, I have to export as mov first. So I tested 5 minutes of streaming and converting, and got a 22mb file. I then looked for a free converter of .mov to .flv. I found "Any Video Conversion" which seems decent, but it only converts 8 seconds of the 5 minutes for some reason.

Is there some other way make a .mov from my sources? Is there an automatic way of adding enough frames to cover an mp3 on the timeline? That might work and might not give the final .mov any fits.

Is there an easy way to convert a .mov or .wav to an .flv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you have to

1. Import the sound to the library
2. Call the sound using the Sound object
3. Export movie as .mov, and make sure it's set to get all the streaming content
4. Convert the resulting .mov with Adobe Media Encoder, which comes with CS5

The Adobe converter at the end did a great job.